# Android SDK Manager Launch issues?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have been stuck with this issue for more than 2 days now . Android SDK manager would not start.

```
[2014-12-17 03:08:13 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜/iâ€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:08:13 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜x86â€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:08:13 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] This version of E:\ECLIPS~1\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java64.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
[2014-12-17 03:08:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-12-17 03:08:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-12-17 03:09:15 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜/iâ€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:09:15 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜x86â€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:09:15 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] This version of E:\ECLIPS~1\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java64.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
[2014-12-17 03:09:15 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-12-17 03:09:15 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-12-17 03:13:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜/iâ€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:13:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜x86â€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:13:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] This version of E:\ECLIPS~1\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java64.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
[2014-12-17 03:13:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2014-12-17 03:13:40 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
[2014-12-17 03:20:16 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜/iâ€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:20:16 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] find: â€˜x86â€™: No such file or directory
[2014-12-17 03:20:17 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] This version of E:\ECLIPS~1\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java64.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
[2014-12-17 03:20:18 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-12-17 03:20:18 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

I have already hard-coded in find_java.bat
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe"

and also in Android.bat
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe"

Also Overwritten the files from http://tools.android.com/knownissues .

Can anybody please help on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program. If it turns out you need the 32bit version, uninstall the Java JDK and then re-install the 32 bit version of the JDK.

Comment: Its 32 bit for sure. Don't know why its searching for 64 bit. I for once deleted find_java64 then also did not helped. Any other point am i missing ?

Comment: You're not reading what I wrote. Please uninstall your current version of the JDK. You installed the wrong one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue, running xp sp2 on a 32 bits processor. I fixed it by hard-coding the arch_ext variable in find_java.bat.

So you should restore your find_java.bat file and simply comment lines 26 and 27

```
26 rem reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" |^
27 rem find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64
```

and then add the following to force the arch_ext variable.

```
set arch_ext=32
```

The instruction 'Query "..." | find /i "x86" > ...' seemed, in my case, to be the source of the problem ("find: '/i': No such file or directory"). I didn't investigate further as the architecture is well known.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan points out, you have installed a wrong `JDK` version, uninstall and install the correct one (32 bits).

Comment: okay I installed fresh jdk from [Link] (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b18/jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe?AuthParam=1418768552_5fe4ed608410955be22b68f3bb06b0a9) . But Still I am Getting the same error.

Comment: How can i get you the Java model installed ? I am sure its x86 now .